# HttpContext.Current.Application.Add() in unit test

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I wrote a simple unit test with HttpContext to add a dummy key with value into Application collection as following

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));

if (!HttpContext.Current.Application.AllKeys.Contains("dummy"))
    HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("dummy", "value");
Assert.IsTrue(HttpContext.Current.Application.AllKeys.Length>0);
```

When debugging, the Add() function works and there is no exception but the collection is still blank after adding. I think I have to initialize some other properties of HttpContext so that Add() functions works. But I don't know which properties are still required.